# Having issues with setting up CS50 IDE

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, cs50

I tried to install CS50 IDE by using containerized app called docker and despite it downloaded most of the stuff, I couldn't install the IDE and not being able to capture the IP address

And here's the terminal code

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'


Creating CA: /Users/atatekeli/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem
Creating client certificate: /Users/atatekeli/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
(default) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at /Users/atatekeli/.docker/machine/cache...
(default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v19.03.12
(default) Downloading /Users/atatekeli/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v19.03.12/boot2docker.iso...
(default) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/atatekeli/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/atatekeli/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running


    
                    ##        .            
              ## ## ##       ==            
           ## ## ## ##      ===            
       /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===        
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~   
       \______ o          __/            
         \    \        __/             
          \____\______/                
    


Error getting IP address: Host is not running
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com


The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ 
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ http://localhost:5050/
bash: http://localhost:5050/: No such file or directory
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ docker run --privileged -e "IP=127.0.0.1" -e "PORT=8080" --name ide50 -d -p 5050:5050 -p 8080-8082:8080-8082 cs50/ide
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/ide50" is already in use by container "a38b300e0768194eef6fbbfd28104b6707c39c603c22565ab76e327a8c28a8ec". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ docker run --privileged -e "IP=$(docker-machine ip default)" -e "PORT=8080" --name ide50 -d -p 5050:5050 -p 8080-8082:8080-8082 cs50/ide
Error getting IP address: Host is not running
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/ide50" is already in use by container "a38b300e0768194eef6fbbfd28104b6707c39c603c22565ab76e327a8c28a8ec". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ docker-machine ip default
Error getting IP address: Host is not running
(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$ docker --ip
unknown flag: --ip
See 'docker --help'.

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options:
      --config string      Location of client config files (default
                           "/Users/atatekeli/.docker")
  -c, --context string     Name of the context to use to connect to the
                           daemon (overrides DOCKER_HOST env var and
                           default context set with "docker context use")
  -D, --debug              Enable debug mode
  -H, --host list          Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -l, --log-level string   Set the logging level
                           ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal")
                           (default "info")
      --tls                Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
      --tlscacert string   Trust certs signed only by this CA (default
                           "/Users/atatekeli/.docker/ca.pem")
      --tlscert string     Path to TLS certificate file (default
                           "/Users/atatekeli/.docker/cert.pem")
      --tlskey string      Path to TLS key file (default
                           "/Users/atatekeli/.docker/key.pem")
      --tlsverify          Use TLS and verify the remote
  -v, --version            Print version information and quit

Management Commands:
  builder     Manage builds
  config      Manage Docker configs
  container   Manage containers
  context     Manage contexts
  image       Manage images
  network     Manage networks
  node        Manage Swarm nodes
  plugin      Manage plugins
  secret      Manage Docker secrets
  service     Manage services
  stack       Manage Docker stacks
  swarm       Manage Swarm
  system      Manage Docker
  trust       Manage trust on Docker images
  volume      Manage volumes

Commands:
  attach      Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container
  build       Build an image from a Dockerfile
  commit      Create a new image from a container's changes
  cp          Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
  create      Create a new container
  diff        Inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem
  events      Get real time events from the server
  exec        Run a command in a running container
  export      Export a container's filesystem as a tar archive
  history     Show the history of an image
  images      List images
  import      Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image
  info        Display system-wide information
  inspect     Return low-level information on Docker objects
  kill        Kill one or more running containers
  load        Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
  login       Log in to a Docker registry
  logout      Log out from a Docker registry
  logs        Fetch the logs of a container
  pause       Pause all processes within one or more containers
  port        List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container
  ps          List containers
  pull        Pull an image or a repository from a registry
  push        Push an image or a repository to a registry
  rename      Rename a container
  restart     Restart one or more containers
  rm          Remove one or more containers
  rmi         Remove one or more images
  run         Run a command in a new container
  save        Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
  search      Search the Docker Hub for images
  start       Start one or more stopped containers
  stats       Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
  stop        Stop one or more running containers
  tag         Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
  top         Display the running processes of a container
  unpause     Unpause all processes within one or more containers
  update      Update configuration of one or more containers
  version     Show the Docker version information
  wait        Block until one or more containers stop, then print their exit codes

Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.

(base) ata-macbook-air:~ atatekeli$
```

Comment: If you put a line with just three backticks ``` in the beginning of the line both before your terminal code and after your terminal code, it will put the code in a code block. That will make it readable for us. I think also you need to tell us what is in the `start.sh` script. I assume that is what you were running to get this output.

Comment: There are numerous possible solutions in this thread https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4066